# Deal with recursive tree and asynchronous event

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, recursion

I have to deal with a recursive tree, every node is a question and the user can answer by clicking on buttons (yes/no choice). The question is only displayed if the user has answered "yes" at the "parent" question. Every question can have 0 to * childrens.

What is the best way to code this kind of problem because javascript can't stop waiting for a click event.

Below I put the code I have done ( Although he can't work this way ), you can get the idea behind this.

```
var Question = 
{
    question: "",
    children: [],

    init: function(q,f){
        this.question = q;
        this.children= f;
    },

    traitement: function()
    {
        // wait for click
        if(answer is yes)
        {
            // save this question
            for(var c=0;c<childrens.length;c++)
            {
                childrens[c].traitement();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

My idea is to save the parent of every children, and run the program by the click event function, when the answer is "no" or there is no more children, I go to the parent and see if they are children.

Thank you

Comment: So you're trying to implement some type of linked list?

Comment: It is more complex, because a Question can have a lot of children, it can be a sort of doubly linked chain, but i'm not sure it's the most efficient data structure, that's why i'm asking.